# How does one prove probability integral transform?

Tags: statistics, probability-theory

How does one prove probability integral transform? So when $Y = F_X(X)$ where $X$ has a continuous distribution for which the cumulative distribution function is $F_X$, why does $Y$ have a uniform distribution? And what would Y's relationship with $\text{uniform}(0,1)$ distribution?

Comment: Why minus vote?

Comment: See the page "How to ask a question" and enumerate the ways in which yours differ.

Answer (score 5):

Write for $t \in (0;1)$,
$$ P(Y \leq t) = P(F_X(X) \leq t) = P(X \leq F_X^{-1}(t)) = F_X(F_X^{-1}(t)) = t.   $$
It is the cdf of the U(0;1).

Comment: Worth mentioning that this is also just an *inverse sample transform* to a standard uniform distribution.

Comment: What if X is not invertible?

Comment: @Peter, we are not inverting $X$ but instead $F_{X}$.  Certainly it could be that this function is not invertible when we define the inverse function in the usual way for functions.  But here we typically define the inverse of a CDF in a different way to guarantee that an inverse always exists, namely, for a CDF we usually define $F^{-1}_{X}(p) = \inf \{x|P(X\leq x) \geq p)$.

Comment: From the answer it is not clear why $F_X$ must be continuous.

Comment: @Addem How can we be sure that $F_x^{-1}(p)$, in this particular definition, is always a real number? Can't it be infinite?